# Лишний вывод строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему в выводе появляется повторный Alice,
да и ещё без "ы" на конце, как это было задуманно? (вместо него там "а")

```
 peoples ={
    'Jone': [7,4,28],
    'Alice': 8,
    'Jaks': 4,
    'Mayble': 4
}

for k,v in peoples.items():
    if k == 'alice':
        print(f"Любимое число {k.title()}'ы - {v}")
    if k == 'mayble':
        print(f"Любимое число {k.title()} - {v}")
    else:
        print(f"Любимое число {k.title()}'а - {v}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что аккуратнее надо с `if else` работать

```
# если k равно alice
if k == 'alice':
    print(f"Любимое число {k.title()}'ы - {v}")

# проверка закончилась

# если k равно mayble
if k == 'mayble':
    print(f"Любимое число {k.title()} - {v}")
else:
    # иначе остальное (в том числе и alice)
    print(f"Любимое число {k.title()}'а - {v}")
```

а вам надо было делать

```
if k == 'alice':
    ...
elif k == 'mayble':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: аа, то есть else привязывается только к if, которое следует до него?

Comment: нет - else пристраивается к конструкции `if...else` или `if...elif...elif...elif..else`
у вас после `if` следовал не `else` и не `elif`, а значит питон считал, что этот if закончился

Answer (score 1):

потому что если в `k` находится `alice` то сработает первый `if`, а второй не сработает и из-за этого запускается `else`. Поэтому место `if/if/else` пишите `if/elif/else`